# Pass data from Controller to Javascript in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use [Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/) following this example [Google Charts Quick Start](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start)

As you see the data is created in the JS as:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);
```

My question is:

If in my controller I get data... How can I pass it to the Javascript of my template file? I have this example JS hooked up in the head of my index.html.erb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need to create a ruby variable in your controller action to hold your values and generate the javascript in the view using them values using <%= %> tags.

Example:
@values would be a name value collection.

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
data.addRows([
    <% @values.each do |v| %>
        ['<%= v.name %>', <%= v.value %>],
    <% end %>
    ]);
```

Example using a js function.

index.js:

```
var values;

function InitPage(valuesFromView)
{
    values = valuesFromView;
}

function InitData()
{
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows(values);
}
```

index.html.erb: Note that I'm using jquery to call InitPage when the page loads, if you're not using jquery your InitPage call would probably be in the onload of the body tag or something similar.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        InitPage([
           <% @values.each do |v| %>
               ['<%= v.name %>', <%= v.value %>],
           <% end %>
        ]);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What if I have the JS in a index.js file in the assets? That doesn't understand of <% %> right?

Comment: If your JS is in an index.js file you can still use the <% %> code to generate a hardcoded js parameter that you would send to your javascript function declared in your index file.

Comment: I elaborated my answer a bit for using external js files.

Comment: If you're using the asset pipeline, rename the file from `.js` to `.js.erb` and it will get processed with the ERB processor as well.

Comment: Nice Travis, I didn't know about this one. :)